# Conditioning on Brownian motion

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I was reading on conditional probability with respect to a partition of a sample space, and I came across the following example:

> Let $(N_t:t\geq0)$ be the Poisson process. Given fixed times $0\leq s\leq t$, let $A=[N_s=0]$ and for all $n\in\mathbb N$, let $B_n=[N_t=n]$. Letting $\mathscr B$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the $B_n$'s,
>   we get that $$P(A|\mathscr B)=\left(1-\frac st\right)^{N_t}.$$

The two *crucial* ingredients of this is that increments in the Poisson process are independent and Poisson distributed, and so we get that
\begin{align*}
P(A|B_n)&=\frac{P(N_s=0\cap N_t=n)}{P(N_t=n)}\\
&=\frac{P(N_s=0\cap N_t-N_s=n)}{P(N_t=n)}\\
&=\frac{P(N_s=0)P(N_t-N_s=n)}{P(N_t=n)},
\end{align*}
and then we easily compute from here.

---

To test my understanding, I tried to see if I could come up with a similar example with Brownian motion $(W_t:t\geq 0)$.

Of course, the events of the form $[W_t=a]$ for $a\in\mathbb R$ have probability zero,
so I decided to define
$$A=[W_s\leq 0]$$
and
$$B_n=\big[W_t\in[n,n+1)\big],\qquad n\in\mathbb Z.$$
(Of course $P(A)=1/2$ by symmetry, but it seems an interesting to compute the probability that the Brownian motion is negative at time $s$ knowing in what interval $[n,n+1)$ the motion lies at some future time).

However, I'm having problems replicating the computations for my example.
Here,
we have that
\begin{align*}
P(A|B_n)&=\frac{P(W_s\leq0\cap W_t\in[n,n+1))}{P(W_t\in[n,n+1))}.\\
\end{align*}
The problem here is that,
since $W_s$ does not have a fixed value,
I cannot write $$P(W_s\leq0\cap W_t\in[n,n+1))$$
as
$$P(W_s\leq0\cap W_t-W_s\in E)$$
for some *nice* set $E$ (I would get $W_t-W_s\in[n-W_s,n-W_s+1)$, which I can't deal with).

---

Any help/hint on how to deal with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Shouldn't that be $(1-{s\over t})$, not $(1+{s\over t})$?

Comment: You are correct. Fixed.